# CoreBluetooth cannot communicate without running app?

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want you to understand to my English skill is not good.
I'm developing an app using CoreBluetooth.

I checked I can do Bluetooth work in the background after running the app once (scanning, connect, get services).
However, I'm wondering if CoreBluetooth communication is possible in the background mode work without running the app at all.

For example, Once measurements are initiated on the peripherals, the central app will detect them and operate in background mode.

Is it possible?
I'm sorry that there is no code. Now I'm there is no method to start that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is [CoreBluetooth State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW10). According to the documentation:

> Because state preservation and restoration is built in to Core Bluetooth, your app can opt in to this feature to ask the system to preserve the state of your app’s central and peripheral managers and to continue performing certain Bluetooth-related tasks on their behalf, even when your app is no longer running.

When you opt in to state restoration, your app will be relaunched into the background on certain BLE related events. In particular, it keeps track of the following:

> - The services the central manager was scanning for (and any scan options specified when the scan started)
> - The peripherals the central manager was trying to connect to or had already connected to
> - The characteristics the central manager was subscribed to

Please be aware that there are limitations to what you can do while your app is using state restoration and background execution (you might be aware of that already).

Hope that helps

P.S.: We have found that state restoration only works while your iOS device is not attached to your development machine via USB cable (might be different with Xcode 9 now).